# A quoted command line with arguments fails

Tags: linux, bash

I'm defining a command in a script as

```
SVN_CMD="${SVN} --config-dir=xyz --username=abc"
```

When the script executes

```
${SVN_CMD} update
```

I get the error that the command below is not found

```
'/usr/bin/svn --config-dir=xyz --username=abc'
```

since it appears the quoted string is being taken as a file name with embedded spaces. This doesn't seem to happen if I define the variable and run the same command interactively. Defining the variable in parentheses seems to resolve the problem. Is that the best approach?

Comment: Just don't use the quotes in the variable assignment. The whole line will be assigned to SVN_CMD anyway, but as separate words.

Comment: First, go read [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (short summary: don't put commands in variables; variables are for data, not executable code). Second, have you set `IFS` to something that doesn't contain a space? If so, that'd explain why it's not splitting the string on spaces... (and BTW setting a nonstandard `IFS` can have all sorts of other weird effects, so it's best to avoid it when not necessary, and when it is necessary set it back to normal ASAP.)

Comment: The quotes are definitely needed. IFS set to $'\n' was the problem.

Comment: That will bite you every time. Best to do `oifs="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'; #do stuff; IFS="$oifs"` which saves `IFS` in `oifs` (*old IFS*) utilizes the new `IFS` as needed and then resets it to the original values ASAP as @GordonDavisson notes.